# Loader when occuring loops in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, loading, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm facing the problem that i need to display the loader when the data loading from the loop.I'm using a large number of data in loop so it would be great if am show loader when occuring the loop cases.Tired the pagebeforeshow and pageshow methods.But it does not work for me.Here is my code.Kindly help me to do this.

```
var lazy_load_group_page_cnt = 1;
var lazy_load_group_limit = 50;
var lazy_load_group_flag = false;

$( "#pg_sms-group" ).on( "pagebeforeshow", function( event ) {

    $('#add_group-notification').empty(); 
    $('#ul_group_list').empty();
    loadSMSGroup(lazy_load_group_limit,lazy_load_group_page_cnt);
 });
 $( "#pg_sms-group" ).on( "pageshow", function( event ) {

 $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
        text: "loading...",
        textonly: false,
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'a',
        html: ""
    });
});
 function loadSMSGroup(limit, page){
    var xmlRequest = getXmlSMSgroupRequest();
    var wsdlURL = getWSDL('callServer');

    lazy_load_group_flag = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: wsdlURL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: xmlRequest,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",

        success: function(xmlResponse) {
            var obj_response = parseResponse(xmlResponse);
            if (obj_response.flag){ 
                loadGroupList(obj_response.data);
            }
            }
        },
        error: function(xmlResponse) {
            //error
        }

    });
    lazy_load_group_flag = false;
    return false;

 }

 function loadGroupList(jsnObj){

        var obj_group_list = jsnObj.groups;

        sessionStorage.setItem("ses_group", JSON.stringify(obj_group_list));

        $.each(obj_group_list, function(ctr, obj) {

            $('#ul_group_list').append('<li>' +
                '<a href="#" class="add-container">' +
                    '<label class="add-container" data-corners="false">' +
                        '<input name="chk_group" id="chk_group" type="checkbox" value="'+obj.groupname+'{group-'+obj.groupid+'}'+'"  />' +
                        '<label class="lbl_add-container">' +
                            '<h3>'+obj.groupname+'</h3>' +'</div>' +
                        '</label>' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</a>' +
                '<a href="#pg_add-group"  onclick="sessionStorage.group_id='+obj.groupid+'"</a>'+
            '</li>');
        });
        $("input[name=chk_group]").checkboxradio();
        $('#ul_group_list').listview('refresh');
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>The page has been created and enhancement is done!</p>
<div id="king">
</div>
<ul data-role="listview" id="ul_group_list" data-inset="true">
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the single-threadedness of JavaScript, you cannot perform monolithic CPU intensive tasks in that way. You can use:

- Web Workers (see examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/))
- a `setTimeout` trick (**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy27J/1/)**)

In both cases, when the "completed" event fires, you have to call `$.mobile.loading("hide");`.

Regarding your code example, see my modified version (untested):

```
<script>
var lazy_load_group_page_cnt = 1;
var lazy_load_group_limit = 50;
var lazy_load_group_flag = false;
var obj_group_list = [];
var counter = 0;

$( "#pg_sms-group" ).on( "pagebeforeshow", function( event ) {

    $('#add_group-notification').empty(); 
    $('#ul_group_list').empty();
    loadSMSGroup(lazy_load_group_limit,lazy_load_group_page_cnt);
 });

 function loadSMSGroup(limit, page){
    var xmlRequest = getXmlSMSgroupRequest();
    var wsdlURL = getWSDL('callServer');

    lazy_load_group_flag = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: wsdlURL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: xmlRequest,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",

        success: function(xmlResponse) {
            var obj_response = parseResponse(xmlResponse);
            if (obj_response.flag){ 
                counter = 0;
                obj_group_list = obj_response.data.groups;
                sessionStorage.setItem("ses_group", JSON.stringify(obj_group_list));
                pump();
            }
        }
        },
        error: function(xmlResponse) {
            //error
        }

    });
    lazy_load_group_flag = false;
    return false;

 }

function worker(loops)
{
    for (var l = 0; l < loops; l++)
    {
        if (counter >= obj_group_list.length)
            break;

        $('#ul_group_list').append('<li>' +
            '<a href="#" class="add-container">' +
                '<label class="add-container" data-corners="false">' +
                    '<input name="chk_group" id="chk_group" type="checkbox" value="'+obj_group_list[counter].groupname+'{group-'+obj_group_list[counter].groupid+'}'+'"  />' +
                    '<label class="lbl_add-container">' +
                        '<h3>'+obj_group_list[counter].groupname+'</h3>' +'</div>' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</label>' +
            '</a>' +
            '<a href="#pg_add-group"  onclick="sessionStorage.group_id='+obj_group_list[counter].groupid+'"</a>'+
        '</li>');

        counter++;
    }
}

function pump()
{
    worker(100);
    if (counter < obj_group_list.length)
        setTimeout(pump, 50);
    else
    {
        $("input[name=chk_group]").checkboxradio();
        $('#ul_group_list').listview('refresh');
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>The page has been created and enhancement is done!</p>
<div id="king">
</div>
<ul data-role="listview" id="ul_group_list" data-inset="true">
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,the mentioned code is just a example.I've checked in JSFiddle.I'm doing the soap ajax call in pagebeforeshow event.After getting the details from server appending the ul_group_list.It so difficult to handling the variables in private.Can you guide me do that ?

Comment: After removing ');' in workers loop,its working great.And we can refresh the list box in workers loop itself.